# Getting Bytes from JSON byte arrays into Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, hex, encode

I am working on a post processing application wherein, in a different C# based application I am storing byte arrays into a list, and then saving said list into a JSON file.  All seems to work out okay on that front and when I reopen the byte array in another C# application there is no issue reading in and interpreting the data.  Where I am running into headache is bringing the data into a python script to post process.  The json file is correctly ingested, however the byte data is in a weird format that I am having trouble interpreting

```
import json

packetTypeDict = {"TxRx":0xABCD,"Cfg":0xA5A1}

def get_dictionary_from_json(jsonFilePath):
    with open(jsonFilePath) as f:
        jsonData = json.load(f)     
    return jsonData    

def parse_json_file(jsonFilePath):
    dataDict = get_dictionary_from_json(jsonFilePath)
    parse_data_list(dataDict["dataList"])

def parse_data_list(dataList):
    print(len(dataList))
    #flatten the list
    dataListFlat = [item for sublist in dataList for item in sublist]
    print(len(dataListFlat))
    print(dataListFlat)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataDict = parse_json_file(r"test.json")
```

When I run this, I end up getting values in the output of the print statement (and in my debugger), which don't seem to match what I see in C#.  The output from the the "print(dataListFlat) command ends up being produced as of a list of strings such that the output looks like this

```
['z', 'a', 's', '4', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'A',...
```

That same array when represented in C# after and before going into JSON looks like this

```
[0]: 0xcd,[1]: 0xab, [2]: 0x38, [3]: 0x00, [4]: 0x01, [5]: 0x00, [6]: 0x00, [7]: 0x00...
```

Which is the format I am looking for.
Additionally, the data inside of the JSON file is represented exactly as it is in the python output

```
"dataList":["zas4AAEAAAAyVGotABAQAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

Ultimately, the C# implementation has access to the source class that defines dataList as a List of arrays of bytes, whereas the python side does not have that knowledge.  So I would assume that there is some way to cast this data into bytes, but I am at a little bit of a loss as to what is going on.  I have looked into using unpack, casting as bytes, plus any number of other approaches.  Nothing I have tried seems to work.  Furthermore, there isn't really an apparent pattern between the python output and the C# output.  Yet clearly there is because Newtonsoft JSON has no issues processing that same character string.

Comment: Addition to this, when I use base64.b64decode(dataList[0]) I do get something that resembles the target output.  But still has some wonky values b'\xcd\xab8\x00\x01\x00\x00\x002Tj-\x00\

Answer (score 0):

And of course I figure out the answer shortly after posting.  Looked into how JSON encodes bytes (and specifically byte[]) and found a [blog post](https://devqa.io/encode-decode-json-byte-array/) where it was discussed that they are usually default encoded to base64.  Was able to decode the byte arrays using the following code on the packets before they are flattened

```
base64.b64decode(dataList[0])
```

This properly converted the individual arrays which matched the output of the JSON deserialize method in C#.
[image]
[image]